# silverlight listbox throwing "value not fall in expected range" even when empty?

Tags: c#, silverlight, listbox

I'm dynamically populating a silverlight listbox, programmatically, with a template control.
the listbox is empty, and when i attempt a listBox.Items.Add(myTemplateControl), it throws the "Value does not fall within the expected range" argumentexception.

i verified in the debugger that the item collection is indeed emtpy.
the only time i've heard of this exception happening is when the list already contains an instance with that name.

any thoughts?

Stack trace:

```
at MS.Internal.XcpImports.MethodEx(IntPtr ptr, String name, CValue[] cvData)
at MS.Internal.XcpImports.MethodPack(IntPtr objectPtr, String methodName, Object[] rawData)
at MS.Internal.XcpImports.Collection_Add[T](PresentationFrameworkCollection`1 collection, Object value)
at System.Windows.PresentationFrameworkCollection`1.AddImpl(Object value)
at System.Windows.Controls.ItemCollection.AddImpl(Object value)
at System.Windows.Controls.ItemCollection.AddInternal(Object value)
at System.Windows.PresentationFrameworkCollection`1.Add(T value)
at KTClientRIA.Documents.b__4(Object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
at System.Net.WebClient.OnDownloadStringCompleted(DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
```

Comment: Can you see what the parameters are in the debugger? (Set Break on all Exceptions)

Comment: what specifically do you mean by "the parameters"?
are you referring to the "myTemplateControl" parameter? it's a custom XAML template control that inherits from UserControl

Comment: No; I mean the parameters to `MS.Internal.XcpImports.MethodEx`

Comment: If you set Break on all exceptions, it will break inside that method, and you should see its parameters in the Locals window.

Comment: http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/164985/372105.aspx give it a unique name.  Also, the ListBox is probably not empty at this point due to a bug in your event handling, betcha.

Comment: will i appreciate it, but as i stated in the description this can't be the issue because this is the first item i add. there's no other item in teh collection to have the same name.
SLaks, i'm trying to set it to break on all exceptions. brb.

Comment: SLaks, i went to "debug > exceptions" and checked all the "thrown" columns and it didn't break on that exception.

Comment: @MVelasquez: I was pointing out the very important difference between an assumption and fact.  Others have had the same issue, and it was caused by more than one item.  They believed same as you, but they had other bugs which was causing more than one item to be inserted.  You need to debug closely, checking to see at runtime if it is truly empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to all the suggestions. I was able to track it down. At another point in time of the life cycle of the silverlight control, there was another listbox completely separate from this one that was adding an item of the same name.
being that both the parent listboxes resided on the same silverlight control, it was blowing up.

Answer (score 0):

I apologize in advance for this being a "non-answer" answer, but maybe it will help.

I had the exact same issue, but with an Accordion instead of a ListBox. My control hierarchy was:

- UserControl (the page)

  - Accordion

    - AccordionItem0

      - ContentControl

        - ReportView0 (dynamically created at runtime and bound to the ContentControl's Content property)
    - AccordionItem1

      - ContentControl

        - ReportView1 (dynamically created at runtime and bound to the ContentControl's Content property)
    - etc.

I was able to populate the accordion's ItemSource and create the ReportView controls the first time, but if I tried to refresh the list (say, to sort it), I would get the "Value does not fall within the expected range" exception.

I believe what was happening was that, when I freshed the list, my manually created ReportView items were never being disassociated from their original parent ContentControls. After the refresh, when attempting to bind the ReportViews to a different AccordionItem, the exception was being thrown because each ReportView was already in the visual tree.

My solution was to get rid of the ContentControl and declare the ReportView control in its place. This way, Silverlight would manage the control in the visual tree.

(I originally used the dynamic approach so that I could use MEF to satisfy imports via GetExportedValue. When I found out about CompositionInitializer.SatisfyImports, I was able to switch to declaring the ReportView in XAML.)

Comment: what's odd is that i'm calling listBox.Items.Clear() to clear out my listbox of the controls that i will dynamically add.
then when i add the new control, before i add it, i added a line to retrieve a control of the same name from the listbox. and it found one.
yet in the debugger, the itemcollection is 0.
i don't understand how it can say the itemcollection count is zero, yet if i do an explicit "find" for a control within the object, it finds it.
so that's why this is happening, it thinks the control already exists in my item collection.