# ObservableCollection throwing ArgumentException on Remove, in an odd pattern (Windows Phone LongListSelector)

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, .net-4.5, observablecollection

I've ran into the following problem and can't seem to figure out what's causing it. Imagine an ObservableCollection with 6 elements.

To add some information because i didn't run into such an issue before: Target is .NET 4.5 ARM (Windows Phone App) and i'm using LINQ to SQL to store my model.

Through the app interface i'm generating a structure like

```
element 1
element 2
element 3
element 4
element 5
element 6
```

Now i'm deleting at position one, so the following items will skip upwards, resulting in the deletion in order
1, 2, 3, 4, 5 <- exception

(So i thought "every 5th. mhmm interesting. maybe something with list auto expansion/shrink")

With this:

```
element 1
element 2
element 3
element 4
element 5
```

1, 2, 3, 4 <- exception

(Now i thought "maybe exception every 2nd last element?")

With this i expected exception at 3:

```
element 1
element 2
element 3
element 4
```

Nope. No exception at all.

Now in other questions somebody found help in enabling all exceptions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8680067/expected-range-error-when-removing-last-item-from-listboxs-observablecollection). Unfortunately in my case the messages from stack trace were not that helpful.

Did someone else run into similar issues with the circumstances i'm having here? (In a WPF 4.0 project i've worked at, i never had such problems with ObservableCollection, so I'm a little confused here.)

EDIT 1: My apologies. I was hoping someone would recognize the pattern by description. So here's some of the code:

Code used for adding:

```
        using (var ctx = GetDbContext())
        {
            var item = new Alert();
            item.IsActive = true;
            item.Message = string.Format("Alert {0}", Alerts.Count + 1);
            item.Target = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(10);

            var vm = new AlertViewModel(item);
            Alerts.Add(vm); // observablecollection
            Overview.Add(vm); // observablecollection

            ctx.Alerts.InsertOnSubmit(item); // linqtosql table<AlertVM> property

            ctx.SubmitChanges();
        }
```

Code used to Delete:

```
    private void ExecuteSubjectDeleteCommand(object o)
    {
        SubjectViewModel c = o as SubjectViewModel;
        if (c != null)
        {
            try
            {
                if (c.Delete())
                {
                    switch (c.SubjectType)
                    {
                        case SubjectType.Alert:
                            Debug.WriteLine("Overview.Remove");
                            Overview.Remove(c);
                            Debug.WriteLine("Overview.Remove-END");
                            Debug.WriteLine("Alerts.Remove");
                            Alerts.Remove(c as AlertViewModel);
                            Debug.WriteLine("Alerts.Remove-END");
                            break;
                        case SubjectType.Timer:
                            Debug.WriteLine("Overview.Remove");
                            Overview.Remove(c);
                            Debug.WriteLine("Overview.Remove-END");
                            Debug.WriteLine("Timers.Remove");
                            Timers.Remove(c as TimerViewModel);
                            Debug.WriteLine("Timers.Remove-END");
                            break;
                        default:
                            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(); // breaking here never entered
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Log.Error(e.Message); // breaking here never entered
            }
        }
    }
```

Place where exception is reported (App.xaml.cs):

```
    // Code to execute on Unhandled Exceptions
    private void Application_UnhandledException(object sender, ApplicationUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Debugger.IsAttached)
        {
            // An unhandled exception has occurred; break into the debugger
            Debugger.Break(); <--- HERE (Exception message: "Value does not fall within the expected range."
        }

        Log.Error(e.ExceptionObject.Message);
    }
```

Oddly enough looking at Debug output the delete Message "Alerts.Remove-END" is comming through, yet somehow there's an exception beeing thrown. When reentering the App the item i've deleted is gone too, so apparently the linqtosql has completed too.

I hope that the provided additional information will suffice.

EDIT 2:

SubjectViewModel:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// deletes on datalayer
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>return true on success</returns>
    public abstract bool Delete();
```

AlertViewModel:

```
    public override bool Delete()
    {
        try
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Deleting");
            using (var ctx = AlertsContext.GetIsoStore())
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Attach");
                ctx.Alerts.Attach(Data);
                Debug.WriteLine("Attach-END");
                Debug.WriteLine("DeleteOnSubmit");
                ctx.Alerts.DeleteOnSubmit(Data);
                Debug.WriteLine("DeleteOnSubmit-END");
                Debug.WriteLine("SubmitChanges");
                ctx.SubmitChanges(ConflictMode.FailOnFirstConflict);
                Debug.WriteLine("SubmitChanges-END");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            Log.Error(exception.Message);
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Output window Output:

```
Deleting
Attach
Attach-END
DeleteOnSubmit
DeleteOnSubmit-END
SubmitChanges
-- CURSOR BASED INDEX DELETE [Alert].[PK_Alert] (
--   Identifier: [28]
--  )
-- EQUALITY CHECK [_version], [System.Byte[]] = [System.Byte[]]
SubmitChanges-END
Overview.Remove
Overview.Remove-END
Alerts.Remove
Alerts.Remove-END
"TaskHost.exe" (CLR C:\windows\system32\coreclr.dll: Silverlight AppDomain):     "C:\windows\system32\en-US\mscorlib.debug.resources.dll" geladen. Das Modul wurde ohne     Symbole erstellt.
Eine Ausnahme (erste Chance) des Typs "System.ArgumentException" ist in     System.Windows.ni.dll aufgetreten.
```

EDIT 3:
with all exceptions enabled i'm getting an exception at this:

```
System.Windows.Rect.Height.set(double value) <-- HERE
Microsopft.Phone.Controls.LongListSelector.UpdateContainerBounds();
Microsopft.Phone.Controls.LongListSelector.HandleItemChanges();
Microsopft.Phone.Controls.LongListSelector.Balance();
Microsopft.Phone.Controls.LongListSelector.MeasureOverride(Size availableSize);
System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureOverride(IntPtr nativeTarget, double inWidth, etc)
```

Comment: this is nowhere near enough information to help you out. **What** exception is being thrown? What does the code look like? Can you reproduce the problem in a sample program (http://www.sscce.org/) ?

Comment: Edenfield is right that there is nowhere near enough info. Sourcecode is always helpful. It could be quite a few different things, and without details its like shooting at a bulls-eye blind.

Comment: I've added some code now. Hopefully that'll help somehow

Comment: We really need a stack trace. I doubt the exception is in `Delete()` because that method takes no arguments and you are claiming to be getting an argument exception. Also, don't use `as` for casting if you know what they type is going to be. Use a regular cast.

Comment: is *your* code throwing the exception you're having a problem with?

Comment: What  does SubjectViewModel.Delete do?  What does SubjectViewModel.SubjectType signify? What are the values of SubjectType?  How can SubjectViewModel.SubjectType have a value of other than Alert or Timer?

Comment: @siride i agree. should not be in the implementation, next edit within 5 minutes will contain more details.

Comment: @PeterRitchie It should not be, otherwise i would expect the debugger to break at a point where i can easily solve this issue myself. the message i'm about to add will show where it's beeing raised.

There are just 2 possible types for SubjectType, the default branch is to make sure i don't forget implenting this in case i'm changing it. it should never land in this branch. My next edit will contain code for delete.

Comment: @AndreasMüller Why would you expect that?  There's code specifically in the project template that arbitrarily breaks in the debugger for *unhandled exceptions*, if you want something more reasonable, then handle the exception.  Alternatively, you can change the debugging settings to break when a particular exception is *thrown*. (see Debug\Exceptions).  If there really is only two possible types for SubjectType, then you should never get to the default on the c.SubjectType switch.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. However that's not what's causing this problem. I want to empathise on the fact, that it all works fine when deleting like this: 5, 4, 3, 2, 1

Comment: how about reopening this? I've found the source of the problem and i'd rather save another person running into the same issue, the time i've spent on fixing this.

Comment: Hi Andreas, it is possible to post the answer to your own question, please do so rather than editing the solution into your question. Providing the answer may indeed help others, but only as a proper answer, not an edit.

Comment: @FionaTaylorGorringe I would have done so - unfortunately it was closed to over eager moderation. I cannot answer on closed questions. Hence i just now voted for reopen so i am able to do just that.

Comment: Ah, didn't notice that. Have voted for re-open so that you can do so.

Comment: @FionaTaylorGorringe That must have made the difference now then. Added it as answer. Thanks for your vote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by swapping the phone:LongListSelector for an ordinary ListBox, which did not have the described proplems when deleting in 1,2,3,4,5 order instead of 5,4,3,2,1. Hence i'm assuming this must be a bug with the control.

If you're working with Windows Phone 8.1 SDK you may try using the LongListSelector again. Maybe they fixed the bug in the meantime. At least there was no changes made to the code other than using the ListBox and it suddenly worked flawlesly.